# Check the existence of both an object and a file with a function in R

Tags: r

I have a script that accepts some arguments in this form:
`Rscript script.R -o=output -x=density.xvg -t=temperature.xvg -u=potential.xvg -p=pressuree.xvg -...`

All the file are `.xvg` (text file) and are structured in columns.

```
#    title "Secondary Structure"
#    xaxis  label "Time (ns)"
#    yaxis  label "Number of Residues"
#TYPE xy
   0   637   180   201     7    94   129   300     0    47     1
   1   617   189   191    11    99   121   294     5    48     1
   2   625   183   198     7    97   130   290     0    53     1
   3   625   180   195     5   102   125   300     0    51     1
```

I call the R script from a bash script that sets all the possible flags, even if some files don't exist.
The R script should check if both file and variable exists and execute the specific function (plot temperature profile, plot density, ..).
The Script first check if a flag is set and assign its value (the file name) to a variable (for `-u=potential.xvg` I get `file.potential <- "potential.xvg"`).

The script then checks the existence of both the variable and the file with

```
if (!exists("file.potential")) {
  cat('the variable "',file.potential,'" is not set\n')
} else {
  if (file.exists(paste(file.potential))) {
    cat("ok\n")
  } else {
    cat('the file "',paste(file.potential),'" does not exist\n')
  } 
}
```

Because I have several flags I wrote a function:

```
checkExistance <- function(a) {
  if (!exists("a")) {
    cat('the variable "',a,'" is not set\n')
  } else {
    if (file.exists(paste(a))) {
      cat("ok\n")
    } else {
      cat('the file "',paste(a),'" does not exist\n')
    } 
  }
}
```

The existence of the variable is checked correctly, but not the existence of the file. Apparently `paste(a)` returns `a` instead of `potential.xvg`.

I have all the functions defined in a separate file that I source at the beginning, but I also tried to define the function in the main script.

What is wrong?

## ------- update 1

I'm parsing the arguments (-d=value1) with this function:

```
parseArgs <- function(x) strsplit (sub("^-","",x), "=")   
argsDF <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", parseArgs(args)))
argsL <- as.list(as.character(argsDF$V2))
names(argsL) <- (argsDF$V1)
```

and then

```
if(is.null(argsL$x)) print("density file not supplied") else file.density <- argsDF$V2[which(argsDF$V1 == "x")]
```

If I then check the existence with`exists("a")` (or `exists("file.density")`) it works, but `exists(a)` gives me this error:

```
Error in exists(a) : invalid first argument
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data (i.e. the value of a typical "a" in your script)? I think I got the problem but I am not 100% sure of what you want to do...

Comment: Please add any relevant data to your original question, not the comment section.

Comment: question update, sorry for that.

Comment: First, your call to `exists` looks for the existence of a variable named "a", not a variable whose name is in the variable "a". Second, if `a` is "file.potential", then shouldn't it be `paste(a, ".xvg", sep="")`?

Comment: In other parts of the script I used (successfully) `exists("file.potential") to check the variable and `file.exists(paste(file.potential)) to check the file.
If I `print(paste(file.potential))` I get the value inside the variable: `potential.xvg`

Comment: Your call to `exists("a")` will work because the variable "a" (the argument to the function) contains a character string which I'm inferring is supposed to be the name of another variable. It is not checking if the variable *referenced by a* exists. Try this: `varstr <- "otherVarName"; exists("varstr"); exists(varstr);`

Comment: You are right, is it wrong to test the existence of the variable with the string `"a"`?

Comment: Check for the existence of the variable named by "a" with `exists(a)` (no quotes). Realize that `exists` takes a character string as its argument, with no presumption or deep interpretation. You provided a string, an "a", and it sees that there is a variable named "a". It is simple and relatively naive in this sense; I prefer it this way, frankly, so that I can do `exists(a)` and it does what I expect.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but `exists(a)` doesn't work.
I edited the main question with details.